# Issue With EF Core ThenInclude Against A Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm running into this compile error when using ThenInclude on a entity. The error is listed below. I can't see anything wrong with the relationships between the two entities. What gives, I'm banging my head against a wall here!

```
'ICollection<OptionType>' does not contain a definition for 'ProductOption' 
and no extension method 'ProductOption' accepting a first argument of type 
'ICollection<OptionType>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or 
an assembly reference?)
```

Here are the two entities in question and related code

```
public async Task<ProductEditor> Edit(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter)
    {
        var product = _repo.Find(filter)
                        .Include(x=>x.OptionType)
                        .ThenInclude(x=>x.ProductOption)

public partial class OptionType
{
    public OptionType()
    {
        ProductOption = new HashSet<ProductOption>();
    }

    public int OptionTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductOption> ProductOption { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductOption
{
    public int ProductOptionId { get; set; }
    public int OptionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsStocked { get; set; }

    public virtual OptionType OptionType { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        EmailLog = new HashSet<EmailLog>();
        OptionType = new HashSet<OptionType>();
        Order = new HashSet<Order>();
        ProductDiscountCode = new HashSet<ProductDiscountCode>();
        ProductPaymentMethod = new HashSet<ProductPaymentMethod>();
        ProductPhoto = new HashSet<ProductPhoto>();
        ProductViewCounter = new HashSet<ProductViewCounter>();
        ProductWishList = new HashSet<ProductWishList>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? SalePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingCost { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool WillShipInternational { get; set; }
    public int QuantityTotal { get; set; }
    public int QuantitySold { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsBold { get; set; }
    public bool IsHighlighted { get; set; }
    public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
    public int ReturnPolicyId { get; set; }
    public int ConditionId { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PostedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmailLog> EmailLog { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OptionType> OptionType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDiscountCode> ProductDiscountCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductPaymentMethod> ProductPaymentMethod { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductPhoto> ProductPhoto { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductViewCounter> ProductViewCounter { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductWishList> ProductWishList { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCondition Condition { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSystemReturnPolicy ReturnPolicy { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you add the Product class?

Comment: Lol I guess that would help...added

Comment: What EF Core version are you on?

Comment: EF Core version 1.1.0

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?